# I have no idea why my Subscriber Collection Factory is not working

Tags: magento2, collection, query, newsletter-subscriber

I have no idea why my Subscriber Collection Factory is not working.
Below is my code. Wish someone can help me to fix my problem. I believe something wrong with my setup of CollectionFactory

```
use Magento\Newsletter\Model\ResourceModel\Subscriber\CollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
        CollectionFactory $subscriberCollection
    ) {
        $this->subscriberCollection = $subscriberCollection;
    }

public function  getSubscriberStatus()
    {

        $subscribers = $this->subscriberCollection->create();
        $subscribers->addAttributeToSelect("*");

/************** don't know why code not keep run after above *****************/

        $currtDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); // Y-m-d h:i:s
        $newDate = strtotime('-1 MONTH', strtotime($currtDate));
        $newDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $newDate);

        $subscribers->addFieldToFilter('change_status_at', ['gteq' => $newDate]);
        $subscribers->addFieldToFilter('change_status_at', ['lteq' => $currtDate]);

        $subscribers->load();

        return $subscribers;

    }
```

my query

```
select * from newsletter_subscriber where change_status_at >=  (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

object manager method

```
public function  getSubscriberStatus()
{
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
    $connection = $resource->getConnection();
    $query = "select * from newsletter_subscriber where change_status_at >=  (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH);";
    $result = $connection->fetchAll($query);

    return $result;
}
```

update:

```
use Exception;
use Magento\Email\Model\BackendTemplate;
use Magento\Framework\App\Area;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
use Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory;
use Zend_Db_Expr;


/**
 * Class Check
 *
 * @package 
 */
class Check
{
    /**
     * @var SerializerInterface
     */
    private $serializer;



    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;

    /**
     * @var TransportBuilder
     */
    private $transportBuilder;

    /**
     * @var BackendTemplate
     */
    private $emailTemplate;

    /**
     * @var Curl
     */
    protected $curl;

    /**
     * @var CustomerRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $customerRepo;


    protected $subscriberCollection;


    /**
     * Check constructor.
     *
     * @param SerializerInterface $serializer
     * @param CollectionFactory   $collectionFactory
     * @param LoggerInterface     $logger
     * @param TransportBuilder    $transportBuilder
     * @param BackendTemplate     $emailTemplate
     * @param CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepo
     * @param Curl $curl
     */
    public function __construct(
        SerializerInterface $serializer,
        //CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        BackendTemplate $emailTemplate,
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepo,
        CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        \Magento\Newsletter\Model\ResourceModel\Subscriber\CollectionFactory $subscriberCollectionFactory,
        Curl $curl
    ) {
        $this->serializer = $serializer;
        //  $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->emailTemplate = $emailTemplate;
        $this->customerRepo = $customerRepo;
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->_subscribersCollection = $subscriberCollectionFactory->create();
        $this->curl = $curl;
    }


  
    public function  getSubscriberStatus()
    {

        $subscribers = $this->_subscribersCollection;
        $subscribers->addAttributeToSelect("*");

        $currtDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); // Y-m-d h:i:s
        $newDate = strtotime('-10 day', strtotime($currtDate));
        $newDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $newDate);

        $subscribers->addFieldToFilter('change_status_at', ['gteq' => $newDate]);
        $subscribers->addFieldToFilter('change_status_at', ['lteq' => $currtDate]);

        $subscribers->load();

        return $subscribers;

    }
```

Comment: what error are you facing ?

Comment: the function not went thru, just like being ignore. I did try to echo something and die(); not print anything at all and just pass thru

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :-**

```
protected $subscriberCollection;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Newsletter\Model\ResourceModel\Subscriber\CollectionFactory $subscriberCollectiona
) {
    $this->subscriberCollection = $subscriberCollection;
}

public function getSubscriberCollection() 
{
    $subscriberCollection =$this->subscriberCollection->create();
    foreach($subscriberCollection as $subscriber)
    {
        print_r($subscriber->getData());
    }
}
```

Comment: I did try this, still not sure, seems something wrong with the "subscriberCollection" it cannot call back original resources. Can you please help to check again on my above setting is correct or not? thanks

Comment: getting any error ??

Comment: the function cannot load, it didn't get the query result. I just update on my question. Can you please help to take a look, I am getting confuse with my head setup.

Comment: @PaulFan first check your block or controller action is working or not...